# Using existential statements in informal mathematical reasoning

Tags: logic, proof-writing, notation, article-writing

In symbolic logic, existence statements are normally written as
$\exists x P$ where $P$ is some smaller statement. The $x$ is *bound* by the existential quantifier and the *scope* of $x$ is $P$. When working in a formal system, the inference rules dictate how to manipulate such a statement (e.g. existential instantiation). But do we have similar strict rules in natural language proofs?

Suppose I have a theorem stating (in english) “there exists an $n$ such that $P$”. What is the proper way to introduce such an $n$ into my argument? Can I take $n$ to be “in scope” outside the theorem? For example, can I simply make an argument like “Let $m$ = $n^2 + 1$. Since we know that $P$, we also know that $R$”. Similarly for a conditional statement “if $P$, then there exists an $n$ such that $Q$” where I know $P$. What is the proper way to “get” the $n$ out of the existential statement for further deduction? Should I use a different name for the variable?

I see my question as being more about proper style than the concept of existential quantification, which I feel quite comfortable with. I need help figuring out how to write mathematics well, so I appreciate  any references to or examples of proofs that use similar deductions.

Comment: "Let" is the key word here: If we know there exists some object with some property, we write "Let $x$ be an object with that property" and then reason using $x$.

Comment: Then should it always be an explicit step? In a derivation such as “$A$. Therefore there exists an n such that $B$”, would I also need a step “let now $n$ be an object such that $B$”. Before continuing my derivation “Let $m = n^2 + 1$. Then $m$ […]”

Answer (score 3):

Just introduce a "fresh" variable (to avoid overloading) and be explicit about what you're doing.

For example, suppose I've proved

- **Lemma**: $\exists x\varphi(x)$.

Next I have some argument. If along the way I want to introduce an object with property $\varphi$, I'll just write "by the Lemma, let $y$ be such that $\varphi(y)$" where $y$ is an **as-yet-unused** variable symbol. This exactly parallels how existential instantiation works formally. Note that $y$ might not be the variable $x$ of the statement of the lemma - that's fine!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does that mean that I *could* use the same letter “$x$” from the lemma when instantiating it as long as $x$ is unused in my surrounding context? Or suppose the existence statement is part of a derivation, e.g. “$A$. $B$. Therefore $∃xC$. since $x$ has property such and such […]”. Is that fine?

Comment: @user100361 Yes, as long as there's no variable overloading.